# Python pandas series multiindex iteration

Tags: python, pandas, series

I've aggregated some data and i'd like to get the aggregation values back into another dataframe. I've aggregated the data like this

```
bycluster_type = df.groupby(['cluster', 'Type'])
tCount = bycluster_type['Type'].agg([len])
```

**Edit:** *From this point i made some mistakes which i've corrected now and added a few new thoughts.*

*tCount* is now a DataFrame with a MultiIndex. What i'd lke to do now is to get the *cluster*, *type* and the corresponding *value* to put it together with some other data in another dataframe. For example:

```
>>> tCount
                 len
cluster Type
1.0     M        1
2.0     M        7
4.0     M        2
```

So the next step is to get the index and the row:

```
index, row = next(tCount.index.values)
```

So what i'd do next is to unzip the *index* tuple into *cluster* and *type* and get the *len* value from the row.

```
cluster, type = index
val = row['len']
```

Is there a more efficent or elegant way of achieving my goal?

**Edit:** Some example data

```
cluster, Type, foo
      1,    M,   f
      1,    T,   o
      1,    S,   o
      2,    M,   f
      2,    M,   o
      3,    T,   o
```

Comment: Can you add some data samples?

Comment: `tCount.to_frame('len').reset_index()`

Comment: The degree of elegance depends on what you want to do and you haven’t given enough information. There are many things we could do. We don’t know which thing to show you.

Comment: Perhaps its `combine_first` or `concat` that you are after. In case the index of the other dataframe is similar then `df2.loc[tCount.index] = tCount.values` might help. We need more clear info for a good answer.

Comment: Hey i've added some sample data. i hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Wen aswell you've also been right but my code was actually wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran your code and found that tCount results in a MultiIndex Dataframe.

You don't need to iterate throug the index, `df = tCount.reset_index()` should do the trick.

Comment: You are right i've just edited it because i noticed i did something wrong.
And thank you very much for the *reset_index()* that's exactly what i was looking for.